# My CSS is not loading in Internet Explorer 11 and Firefox! Only works with Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Im creating a simple webpage. My CSS is only working in Chrome. It doesnt work in both Firefox and IE11.

Here's my HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>text</title>
    <link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="css/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
</head> 
    <body>
        <h1><b><u>Adding a new Visitor</u></b></h1><br/></br>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <figure>
                <img src="images/advis1.png"/>
                <figcaption style="padding-top: 12px;">text</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <hr/>
            <figure>
                <img src="images/advis2.png"/>
                <figcaption style="padding-top: 12px;">text</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <hr/>
            <figure>
                <img src="images/advis3.png"/>
                <figcaption style="padding-top: 12px;">text.</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <hr/>
            <h3><u>Result</u></h3> 
                <img src="images/advis4.png"/>
                <br/>
                <img src="images/advis5.png"/>
            </div>
            <footer>
                Author: Malcolm Tanti | Contact information: <a href="mailto:xxx">xxxxm</a>
            </footer>
    </body>
```

And here is my CSS

```
h1 {

    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: double;
    border-left: double;
    border-right: double;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: #C4CEDD;
    box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px #000000;
}

body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:none;
    background-color: #7ea2d6;
    font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Helvetica Rounded", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px #000000;
    border: double;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #C4CEDD;
}

img { 
   border:3px double;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

footer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

I am quite new to CSS but and HTML. It works prefectly fine in Chrome which leads me to wonder what the problem is. My Problem is that none of the css loads and that all images and text are not aligned. I do not even have anycolours

Comment: `type="text/css"` not `type="css/stylesheet"` but you don't need that anyway. Chrome will it almost anything you serve him, but other browsers aren't that way ;)

Comment: Have you tried CTRL F5? Maybe IE and FF have something cached?

Comment: Actually! It worked type="text/css" Thanks a lot @mdesdev

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Do you see anything at all or are the elements just not positioned the way you intended?

Comment: I edited the post! but I solved it with help of @mdesdev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by using `type="text/css"` instead of `type="css/stylesheet"` when importing the stylesheet.

Answer (score 6):

I tested your code and found that if you remove type="css/stylesheet" from:

```
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="css/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
```

so it looks like:

```
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

You also don't need the closing / at the end.

It fixes the issue. (Tested on standards mode not quirks)

And you shouldn't need to do this:

```
<h1><b><u>Adding a new Visitor</u></b></h1><br/></br>
```

The underline, font-weight and spacing (margin/padding) should be done in your CSS:

```
<h1>Adding a new Visitor</h1>

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: double;
    border-left: double;
    border-right: double;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: #C4CEDD;
    box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px #000000;

    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm, Thanks! I see what you mean

Answer (score 1):

for internet explorer add this

```js
 
<!--[if lt IE 9]
< script src = "//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" > < /script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: you realize that this code only applies to IE9 or lower right?

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of browser cache. Please clear browser cache by CTRL + F5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and none of the above fixed my issue. In my case, in the end, the solution was simple:

Somehow IE doesn't load the CSS if you are running the page locally (as in stand-alone in your browser). I uploaded the exact same script to a webserver and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

msvk_23 is right.
I had a local html page, instead of post-it.
After I have installed Notepad++ it was all messed up in Internet Explorer and Edge, but not in Google Chrome.
When checking registry it said: text/xml
After changing this to text/css as suggested, it worked immediately in both Internet Explorer and Edge.

Thanks msvk_23 :)

pic of regedit
[image]

Answer (score -4):

Try this option:

Please run regedit.exe and navigate to the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes.css

Modify: "Content Type" from "text/plain" to "text/css"

For me the css was not at all recognizing in IE 11. By changing this entry in regedit. It perfectly worked in my PC.

Comment: Editing the PC registry to make a css work isn't a solution!

Comment: Thanks for trying but this fixes only your PC and is very heavy handed. Fix the code and it will be fixed without reg editing. Also, this could have unintended effects on other things in your browser.