# External CSS not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have wrote my own embed-server, which can generate response to web browsers.
The generated "main page" is like the following html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"><title>ABC Inc. Web Configurator</title></head><body>
<nav><p>[<b>Home</b>]</p></nav>
<table>
<tr><td><a href=Config>Config</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href=Logger>Logger</a></td></tr>
</table>
<footer>Web Configurator &copy; ABC Inc. 2014 - 2015</footer></body></html>
```

And the generated CSS file is

```css
.even{
 background-color: #EFF;
}
.odd{
 background-color: #FFE;
}
.title{
 background-color: #226;
 color: #EEF;
}
a{
 color: #36C;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
body{
 font-family: Tahoma;
 font-size: 100%;
}
footer{
 color: #999;
 font-size: 0.7rem;
}
nav{
 background-color: #DDF;
 font-size: 1.1rem;
}
td{
 min-width: 60px;
}
```

When I browse the main page by Chrome 43 or Firefox 39, they're both okay.
However, when I use IE11, the CSS not apply to the html, even though that I can make sure IE11 have access the CSS file from my server. If I press F12 in IE, the DOM manager shows no stylesheet in this page.

BTW, my URL is http://localhost:8888/, and need a basic authentication.
Any idea how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

1. I've read [the stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335324/external-css-in-internet-explorer-11-not-working) before, and I'm sure my problem is not about browser caching. Thanks Mauro for notification.
2. I've tried Chrome + IE tab2, the CSS works, but not apply to nav and footer tag. I guess IE tab not support HTML5.

**UPDATE**

1. I've try both of closed and non-closed link tag, both of them are not solve my problem with IE11.
2. I've try to disable Basic Authentication, still not working.

**UPDATE**

1. The CSS also works in Firefox 39.
2. The CSS works with IE11 + Compatible mode (but HTML5 tags will be ignored).

Comment: could it be caching rather than an issue? open developer tools and press CTRL-F5, does that then load the style sheets?

Comment: Can you access the CSS file directly from IE11 (not via the page itself) and without authenticating?

Comment: it might look like the issue with the loading the css file

Comment: @Mauro: No, it's not the cache problem. I've read another thread about this, but I forgot to said in my article. Thanks for your notification.

Comment: @LDJ: Hmm, no. Accessing the CSS directly need authentication too.

Comment: your `link` tag isn't closed, might be causing ie11 to ignore it

Comment: @atmd: Thanks for notification, but my original design is closed tag (single link tag end with "/>" ). I've read some articles and modified it to non-closed tag. Anyway, it's not the point that why IE11 not working :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old problem, but I ran into it trying to solve the same problem with my webserver.

IE/Edge was not honouring the css generated by my (custom-built) webserver. The problem was when my webserver returned the css it didn't mark the mime-type as css and IE/Edge reported (hidden in its console output):

```
SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch.
```

Fix was simply to mark the HTML response mime-type as "text/css" and all was OK.
Note that all the other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Android) I tried had no problem with the incorrect mime-type, they just got on with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this attribute to the link tag:
type="text/css"
Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen">
```

Comment: In addition your title CSS is for class named title and won't be applied to the title tag <title> you used in your HTML.

Comment: thanks for reply, however, it's still not work :'(
BTW, the .title is not  design for title tag. (and color attribute can not apply to title, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

After I compare a lot of website, I find out this problem could be solved easily by just remove the html5 declaration `<!DOCTYPE html>`. However, I don't understand why IE11 act like that, it should have support html5.

PS. I've read [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914190/my-css-is-not-loading-in-internet-explorer-11-and-firefox-only-works-with-chrom) and add `type="text/css"`, but it seems IE11 never care about that.

Answer (score 0):

Check if **HTML1202** issue described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=CS-CZ&k=k(VS.WebClient.Help.HTML1202)) can resolve your problem.

if so, check this: [How to avoid ie8 compatibility button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637039/how-to-avoid-ie8-compatibility-button)

Comment: Hmm... I guess my problem is different with HTML1202. However, if I turn on compatible mode in IE11, the CSS will be applied normally.